# Sorting a dictionary which has values as list, and sorting based on the elements inside this list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
A={'k3': ['b', 3],'k2': ['a', 1],'k1': ['a', 3],'k4': ['c', 2],'k5': ['b', 2]}
```

I want to sort the above dictionary first by letters 'a','b' and 'c' in an ascending order

and then based on values 3,2,1 in the descending order. So my output should look something like

```
A={'k1': ['a', 3],'k2': ['a', 1],'k3': ['b', 3],'k5': ['b', 2],'k4': ['c', 2]}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are unordered, so you can't create a sorted dictionary.

If you just want a list of dictionary keys, sorted by the associated values, you could use [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) like this:

```
>>> keys = sorted(A, key=lambda k: (A[k][0], -A[k][1]))
>>> keys
['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k5', 'k4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python recently added an OrderedDict

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK dictionaries have no concept of "order"

Answer (score 0):

You can not sort dicts - there is no ordering defined on dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries are not sortable.  You need may wish to use a list instead.

For example, your input could be represented as a list of tuples:

```
A=[('k3', ['b', 3]),('k2', ['a', 1]),('k1',['a', 3])...]
```

And we could sort it like so:

```
A=sorted(A, key=lambda x: (x[1][0], -x[1][1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. it works. All the while I have done sorting using itemgetter() which works pretty well when things are not nested

Comment: You need to 'accept' the answer (which puts a tick against it). You should probably do it to the other questions you've asked too.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
sorted(A, key = lambda x: (A[x][0], -A[x][1]))
```

At least it gives you the order for the keys.